Compilation Hangs Indefinitely in LaTeX with Colon in Equation
I'm currently using Visual Studio Code with the LaTeX Workshop extension and compiling my document using pdflatex.
In the process of writing my thesis, I've encountered a peculiar issue. Whenever I include a colon in any equation, the compilation process never completes. It neither finishes compiling nor displays any error messages. This issue arises even when adding a seemingly harmless line to a document that otherwise compiles without problems. For example:
$T: \mathcal{M} \rightarrow \mathcal{N}$

Including the above line results in an endless compilation process. However, If I use \text{:}, it works!
Is this a known problem? Could it be related to a specific package?
Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Here an example where I have the error:
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[paperwidth=210mm,paperheight=297mm,top=1.4in, bottom=2in, left=1.25in, right=1.25in,headheight=14pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[frenchb, english]{babel}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\mathtoolsset{centercolon}

\begin{document}

hello party people!

\selectlanguage{french}

hello party people!

$T: \mathcal{M} \rightarrow \mathcal{N}$

\end{document}


Please help us help you and add a minimal working example (MWE) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with \documentclass{...} and ending with \end{document}.

you presumably have some macros you have not shown giving : a non standard behaviour, but if you show no code, it's impossible to help

thank you for your comment!
I tried to create a MWE, and by doing this I found that the culprit was the option \mathtoolsset{centercolon} in the package \usepackage{mathtools} combined with \selectlanguage{french}, removing this makes the build complete!
I included in minimal example where I have the error!

@jlab I included an example

@DavidCarlisle I included an example

Not an answer. Tried your MWE, pdflatex hangs, but xelatex and lualatex compiles it just fine.

From mathtools manual: Warning: centercolon *does not work* with languages that make use of an active colon, most notably *French*. Sadly the babel package does not distinguish between text and math when it comes to active characters. Nor does it provide any hooks to deal with math. So currently no general solution exists for this problem. (31)

You can do e.g. \AddToHook{cmd/(/before}{\let:\vcentcolon} \selectlanguage{french} \let\frenchcolon: \AddToHook{cmd/)/after}{\let:\frenchcolon} \selectlanguage{english} right after \begin{document} and then e.g. \(:\) works as expected, but you'd have to do this for every environment/command you wanted to use for maths. (And I don't know how to do it for $...$.) You need a hook for maths mode, but I don't see one ....

As said by @cfr, \mathtoolsset{centercolon} doesn't work with french babel if you use pdflatex (it works with xelatex and lualatex as said by @mas). But you can still use a normal colon : or a vertically centered colon \vcentcolon. You lost only the automatic replacement of : by \vcentcolon provided by \mathtoolsset{centercolon}.

By the way, frenchb for Babel is deprecated, you should use french instead.

replacing the colon by \vcentcolon in math mode works as suggested by @jlab

TL;DR
Don't use the centeredcolon option when babel-french is used in the document.
Long answer (with no real solution, sorry)
What's happening here? The poor colon is under attack from both babel-french and mathtools.
The former makes the colon active, in order to comply with the traditional (and horrible, but that's just personal opinion) French typesetting rules. The latter instead makes the colon math active.
So, what happens? The active colon is like a macro and its action is

remove a possible space, add the proper (nonbreaking) one, then insert a nonactive colon and another space

The action of the math active colon, as intended by mathtools should be

substitute the colon with a slightly raised one

and the details of how this is done are irrelevant.
The problem is a “race condition”.
What does TeX generally do when it finds a math active character? It looks for the definition of the character as if it were active and performs the action. But when babel-french is used, the colon is active, so this is what happens:

the colon is replaced by its definition as a macro;
TeX obeys the rules, so it inserts an ordinary colon (see later);
the ordinary colon is math active, so the definition of mathtools replaces it with its definition as an active character;
we're in the same situation as step 1… Infinite loop.

The current definition of the active colon, in babel-french, is
\declare@shorthand{french}{:}{%
  \ifFB@spacing
    \ifhmode
      \ifdim\lastskip>1sp
        \unskip\penalty\@M\FBcolonspace
      \else
        \FDP@colonspace
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
  \string:}

Some protection for math mode is actually present: when the active : is found in math mode the conditional \ifhmode returns false, so just \string: is issued. But this doesn't solve the problem, as seen, because \string: inserts a nonactive colon, but it is math active as per the option you pass to mathtools, so the definition as an active character is used, which results in an ordinary colon to be inserted and so on.
The definition mathtools does of the math active colon is never used, because it's superseded by babel.
How could the problem be solved? I see a possible strategy.

babel-french should do, instead of just \string:,
\ifmmode\maybemathtoolscolon\else\string:\fi

define \maybemathtoolscolon at begin document, so it can be checked whether mathtools has been loaded; if it is, then it can be defined to be \mathtoolscolon, otherwise a standard \string:

mathtools should define \mathtoolscolon to be \ordinarycolon if the centeredcolon option is not active or \mathrel{\mathop\ordinarycolon} otherwise.


As things stand, there's no hope of making the centeredcolon option of mathtools usable along with babel-french.
All of the above doesn't happen with LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, because in these cases babel-french uses altogether different methods for spacing the colon in text.
